# TranslateZoomRotateBehavior on elements in ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I need to dynamically create instances of my View CardSmall. So I decided to use an `ItemsControl`. Now I want to attach `TranslateZoomRotateBehavior` to all elements in the `ItemsControl` for touch interaction. If I create an element in the ItemsControl like this it works fine:

```
<ItemsControl> 
        <local:CardSmall>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ei:TranslateZoomRotateBehavior/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </local:CardSmall>
</ItemsControl>
```

But as soon as I define the ItemsSource

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CardsCollection}" >
...
```

Drag Interaction with touch gets really shaky. Not like it is not smooth but more like this is not provided. Meanwhile the Drag Interaction with the mouse works like a charm. Using the MouseDragElementBehavior has a similar effect. But instead of shaky control with touch it just won't work at all when the ItemsSource is defined, neither with touch nor with mouse.

Does anyone else encountered this and has a solution or alternative? Oh and by the way, ScatterView is not a choice right now.

Comment: How are you applying the behaviour when you specify the ItemSource?

Comment: Just like in the code snippet above.

Comment: Are you sure your first snippet is correct? It makes no sense to me at all. ItemsControl content is set by ItemsSource or Items, not with inline xaml. And your CardSmall control has behaviours as content?

Comment: I know that the way it is above I won't be able to dynamically create new Cards. This have do be done with the DataTemplate Tag. But this snippet above is like a test scenario and what I wanted to express with it is that as soon as ItemsSource is defined the drag interaction will not work anymore. It does not really matter in which way the Items are implemented. Additionally it makes do difference if I add the behavior in the UserControl of the Card or like above. I hope this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

I am finding the same behavior, really bad shaking when moved with touch but moves smoothly with a mouse.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
    x:Class="DragTest.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <Grid Background="#FFE01E1E" Width="100" Height="100">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ei:TranslateZoomRotateBehavior RotationalFriction="1" 
                    TranslateFriction="1"/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
        <Canvas Height="250" Width="250"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}">
    <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         Width="100" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate1}" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
         ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```